# tutorial of node.js code sample fails with Error: listen EADDRINUSE

Tags: node.js

I am a beginner programmer that is trying to learn node.js using the following tutorial site
http://www.nodebeginner.org/#hello-world

I got to the point where I was trying to set up the server but got an error with the below code

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

error:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:884:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1022:14)
    at listen (net.js:1044:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1110:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.........../server.js:7:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: Please check this link . It contains related answer
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47992296/7500363)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EADDRINUSE means that address is in use.

Basically, you tried to start two servers at the same time that both use port 8888.  You have to stop or kill one before starting another.  The other server on port 8888 could be another process running your node script, or it could be something else in the system that serves content on port 8888.

Alternatively, you can get this if you don't let the socket settle for a few seconds after terminating the old server.

Comment: Can I solve this by simply changing the port number, or there is a one designated port number?

Comment: Yes, you can change from 8888 to something else.

Comment: Note:  You need to run as root to use a low port number, I think below 1024, and there is no reason to do that.  So... try 8889 or 10000

Comment: If you run nginx as a web server on port 80 of the host ip address, it is fairly straightforward to get it to forward certain requests to a node.js running on localhost:8889 or wherever, get the responses and send it back to the web visitor.  Apache might also be able to do it.  Thats why most people never really need to run node on port 80.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please use the green checkbox to accept it.  You can wait until you are sure.  Thanks.

Comment: @Paul ..... Hey I was having a similar error .... I was wondering How to free the port that is in use ?

Comment: @Devrath To free the port find the program or service that is using the port and terminate it.  If you really don't know how to do that and are certain the port is not normally in use, you could reboot the server if it is your server.

Answer (score 1):

A more practical answer based on [this great one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30163868/5941620).

Find out what is using port 8888 with this command:

```
lsof -i tcp:8888
```

You should get something like this:

```
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
node    86456   myName   13u  IPv6 0xa6b50fb47c9c3c81      0t0  TCP *:ddi-tcp-1 (LISTEN)
```

Now that you know which process is in the way, KILL IT! Softly, like so:

```
kill -15 86456
```