# Using multiCapabilities with protractor causes EADDRINUSE error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am using protractor to run my suite of test. If I use protractor's `capabilities` option, all the tests run fine on all three major browsers (firefox. chrome, safari)

However, If I use `multiCapabilities` as such

```
  multiCapabilities: [{
    'browserName': 'firefox'
  }, {
    'browserName': 'safari'
  }, {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  }],
```

I get an EADDRINUSE error for two of them (not always the same) while the other one passes. How can I fix this:

start of error message:

```
PID: 87414 (capability: safari #2)
Specs: /Users/nicolasmoise/Documents/Projects/otogo/otogo-direct/test/e2e/e2e.spec.js
Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub


Error: listen EADDRINUSE
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1042:14)
    at listen (net.js:1064:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1138:5)
```

Answer (score 2):

EADDRINUSE means that the port number which listen() tries to bind the server to is already in use.

So, in your case, there must be something running a server on that port already.

Check your processes.

[How to fix Error: listen EADDRINUSE while using nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/nodejs-error-listen-eaddrinuse)