# Getting EADDRINUSE connect EADDRINUSE when protractor unable to find element

Tags: angular, typescript, protractor, e2e-testing

When I run e2e test suite it exits in the middle of test giving error EADDRINUSE connect EADDRINUSE. I am running protractor on production instance. 
It is happening when protractor was not able to find elements.
It looks like there are some running process that got created by the webdriver-manager on selenium server neither completed nor terminated correctly.

User is trying to pass `ng e2e --serve=false --base-href=https://`.... in *batch scripts* that *triggers protractor* and it will starts the test but sometimes due to frequent development releases of application or it happens when protractor was not able to find elements, might be some reason too.So, when it occurs the execution of scripts stop in middle(after successfully running n number of cases ). 
So **what will be possible resolution** that user can able to handle these interrupts by code or any measures.

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24875865/6331748

Comment: @ Kacper: I didn't get solution there. I have specified that I am running protractor on production instance not locally. It happens when some element was not found by protractor and some process are not terminated properly on selenium server. I need solution where I can handle such kind of error using some recovery method in my code.

Comment: what browser and how do you run it, update your question, please

Comment: I agree with @Kacper that you are starting a server that is currently in use. So if you are starting a selenium standalone server on port 4444 (with webdriver-manager) and you already have an instance of selenium standalone server, then this will not work giving you an EADDRINUSE. I would check if you already have a java process running the selenium standalone jar file on port 4444.

Comment: Posting because there is no answer here https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4447

Answer (score 0):

when we are disabling browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false) and running parallel execution then after sometime this error (EADDRINUSE connect EADDRINUSE) will occurs.

Solution: we have to make sure that we have disabled waitforAngularEnabled for all the places in our all scripts.
It worked for me. Hope this will help for you also

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30572732)