# Using port 80 with Node on Digital Ocean Error: listen EADDRINUSE

Tags: node.js, port, digital-ocean

I am trying to run the simplest of node servers on a Digital Ocean server. I developed and tested the code using `port 8080` without problems.  However, now I want to use `port 80` so that I do not need to specify the port when navigating to the ip address of my server (so it will default).

When I change the port to `80` and run the app as `sudo` I get `Error: listen EADDRINUSE` even when I do not have any other applications running on the server (at all).  Is there a way to clear `port 80` for use?

I checked here [How to fix Error: listen EADDRINUSE while using nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/nodejs-error-listen-eaddrinuse)
but none of those suggestions worked.  This is definitely the only program on my server.

There are no other processes in my code that are listening on any port. There is actually no app running on my server at all so I do not understand how the port could be in use. Thanks for any help

Edit. Here is what running `netstat` returns:

```
Active Internet connections (w/o servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 192.241.228.76:ssh      mobile-166-137-17:62351 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.241.228.76:ssh      199-241-200-214.P:41732 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.241.228.76:9090     199-241-200-214.P:38480 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.241.228.76:ssh      mobile-166-137-17:45329 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.241.228.76:ssh      199-241-200-214.P:47247 ESTABLISHED
tcp        0    308 192.241.228.76:ssh      199-241-200-214.P:44441 ESTABLISHED
Active UNIX domain sockets (w/o servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
unix  8      [ ]         DGRAM                    7710     /dev/log
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1113212  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7405     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7394     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1113211  
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    9255     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7681     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7617     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1113404  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1113682  
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1113070  
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1113287  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1113683  /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1113675  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7601     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7602     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7631     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1114471  
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1111881  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1113411  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1113219  /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1113218  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1112008  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8858     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    7439     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7682     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     8836     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1114472  
unix  3      [ ]         DGRAM                    7438     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1113412  /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1113676  
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1113552  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1113405  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7616     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     7594     
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1112002  
unix  2      [ ]         DGRAM                    1114349  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1112001  
unix  3      [ ]         STREAM     CONNECTED     1112009  /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
```

And here is what running `ps -ax` returns

```
 PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
    1 ?        Ss     0:05 /sbin/init
    2 ?        S      0:00 [kthreadd]
    3 ?        S      0:01 [ksoftirqd/0]
    5 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/0:0H]
    7 ?        S      0:09 [rcu_sched]
    8 ?        S      0:00 [rcu_bh]
    9 ?        S      0:00 [migration/0]
   10 ?        S      0:14 [watchdog/0]
   11 ?        S<     0:00 [khelper]
   12 ?        S      0:00 [kdevtmpfs]
   13 ?        S<     0:00 [netns]
   14 ?        S<     0:00 [writeback]
   15 ?        S<     0:00 [kintegrityd]
   16 ?        S<     0:00 [bioset]
   17 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/u3:0]
   18 ?        S<     0:00 [kblockd]
   19 ?        S<     0:00 [ata_sff]
   20 ?        S      0:00 [khubd]
   21 ?        S<     0:00 [md]
   22 ?        S<     0:00 [devfreq_wq]
   23 ?        S      2:16 [kworker/0:1]
   24 ?        S      0:00 [khungtaskd]
   25 ?        S      0:00 [kswapd0]
   26 ?        SN     0:00 [ksmd]
   27 ?        S      0:00 [fsnotify_mark]
   28 ?        S      0:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
   29 ?        S<     0:00 [crypto]
   41 ?        S<     0:00 [kthrotld]
   44 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_0]
   45 ?        S      0:00 [scsi_eh_1]
   65 ?        S<     0:00 [deferwq]
   66 ?        S<     0:00 [charger_manager]
  119 ?        S      0:04 [jbd2/vda-8]
  120 ?        S<     0:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
  254 ?        S      0:00 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
  259 ?        Ss     0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --daemon
  321 ?        Ss     0:00 dbus-daemon --system --fork
  351 ?        Ss     0:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
  354 ?        Ssl    0:19 rsyslogd
  363 ?        S      0:00 upstart-file-bridge --daemon
  367 ?        S<     0:00 [kpsmoused]
  371 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/0:2]
  463 ?        S<     0:00 [kvm-irqfd-clean]
  730 ?        S      0:00 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
  773 tty4     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty4
  777 tty5     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty5
  783 tty2     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty2
  784 tty3     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty3
  786 tty6     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty6
  811 ?        Ss     0:12 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
  817 ?        Ss     0:00 acpid -c /etc/acpi/events -s /var/run/acpid.socket
  819 ?        Ss     0:02 cron
  821 ?        Ss     0:00 atd
  898 tty1     Ss+    0:00 /sbin/getty -8 38400 tty1
  933 ?        S<     0:00 [kworker/u3:1]
  938 ?        S      0:00 [kauditd]
24995 ?        S      0:00 [kworker/u2:1]
29226 ?        S      0:07 [kworker/u2:0]
29542 ?        Ss     0:00 SCREEN
29543 pts/2    Ss+    0:00 /bin/bash
30826 pts/6    Ss+    0:00 -bash
30892 ?        Sl     0:00 nodejs index.js
30962 pts/1    R+     0:00 ps -ax
```

Comment: netstat ? what does it say?

Comment: Hmm, I just started killing processes and now it works.  I wonder which it was.  At least I got it working now.  Thanks for telling me about `netstat`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error. It seems that Node will throw this error, even if the address isn't in use, if it fails to attach the process to the port for any reason.

In my case (a Digital Ocean droplet) attaching to port 80 required `sudo`.