# Restart node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm just approaching `node.js`, so I'm running the obvious example - in a file called *server.js*:

```
var http = require("http");

function onRequest(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("it's alive!");
    response.end();
}

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
```

I run this from terminal with `node server.js` and all it's ok, server responds.

**But** when I need to change the *server.js*:

- I made my changes on file;
- write again `node server.js`;

server responds me with the following error:

```
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8888
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1237:14)
    at listen (net.js:1273:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1369:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/lizardhq.com/httpdocs/server.js:9:30)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
```

what I'm doing wrong? Many thanks.

Comment: use `supervisor` https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor or `nodemon` https://github.com/remy/nodemon

Comment: Press control+c in the terminal running the original server to end it before running the second one.

Comment: Press Ctrl + C to stop the first server which is running. It sounds like you've opened 2 terminals. Both servers can't be listening to the same port.

Comment: Do you understand the error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [nodejs Error: listen EADDRINUSE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/nodejs-error-listen-eaddrinuse)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means you've already got a Node.js server (or some other server) running on port `8888`. You need to STOP your other process which is using that port before you can start your Node server on the same port =)

Only one program can bind to a port at a time.

Comment: Ok, but why the first time it's ok? First time I use this port to node.js it runs well.

Comment: The port wasn't in use to start with. After running it, the port is now being used. To test this you could try starting it again and specifying a different port (which isn't being used.)

Answer (score 1):

The error you encounter means your server was not properly shutdown, or is still shutting down, and the port he's listening on is still in use.

You could wait a few minutes for the port to become available, or, if you are using linux, you could find the process id (`PID`) that is using the port via `lsof | grep 8888` which will give you a PID in the second column, and then kill it via `kill -9 PID`.

You could also use [`supervisor`](https://github.com/petruisfan/node-supervisor) and `npm` to watch for change to your file system, and restart your server automagically:

Install `supervisor` :

```
npm install supervisor -g
```

Then, in your `package.json` file, add this line:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "supervisor -w 'server.js' node server.js"
},
```

Now, start your server using the following command:

```
npm start
```

Now, every time you save the `server.js` file, your server will restart automaticaly. No more `EADDRINUSE` error !

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it happens to me, open the task manager | ps -a depending system and kill node process