# Ubuntu open/unblock ports for nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, socket.io, port

I'm trying to listen port 8080 for socket.io but I get error:

```
http://localhost:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Lai1FQh net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

I'm using ubuntu virtual machine from digitalocean and first when I ssh login I get message:
 `The "ufw" firewall is enabled. All ports except for 22, 80, and 443 are BLOCKED`.

I'm beginner with this but doesn't that mean that port `8080` is blocked.
How do I fix this and what I need to do

Here is my code for server:

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var http = require( 'http' );

var app = express();
var server = http.createServer( app );

var io = socket.listen( server );

server.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("Listening");
})
```

In my website i just connect to that port like this:

```
<script src="node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:8080' );
    ...
<script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message you get means that `ufw` (it's a firewall) is blocking all ports except those 3.

To enable port `8080`:

```
sudo ufw allow 8080
```

Then reboot your server.

(As seen from the [guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-firewall-with-ufw-on-ubuntu-14-04) available on your hosting provider website)

Comment: `Rule added Rule added (v6)` but didn't help

Comment: Do you see something about port 8080 if you run `sudo ufw status verbose`?

Comment: I see `8080 ALLOW IN Anywhere` and `8080 (v6) ALLOW IN Anywhere (v6)`

Comment: try `sudo ufw allow out 8080` please

Comment: I get nodejs error `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs/41248876#41248876

Comment: Well, let's try to disable the firewall... `sudo ufw disable`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131366/discussion-between-pietrovismara-and-tonza).

Comment: Thank you for you chat time. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably have another instance of your program running, or some other program that uses that port. Run:

```
ps aux
```

in your shell to see what processes are running and kill those that shouldn't be running. You can also run `lsof` or `netstat` to see what is listening on which port. See the manuals for those commands.

If you can open 8081 or something like that but not 8080 then it means that something is already listening on port 8080. You can verify it with trying to connect to that port with `curl`, `wget`, `netcat` or by using `nmap`. See their man pages for details.