# nodejs error EADDRINUSE

Tags: node.js, port

I get this when i type "node site.js" im 100% sure im not running this node twice.

```
    Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1045:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1262:14)
    at listen (net.js:1298:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1376:9)
    at Server.listen.Server.attach (/root/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:228:9)
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/root/nodejs/site.js:1005:29)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:365:14)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:237:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:207:5)
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000 }
```

Im using FEDORA 23

Comment: Can you show your `site.js`?

Comment: Aren't you trying to listen on the same port twice **in the very same app**? The first one succeeds, the other one just fails.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/47344272/3994271

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Error: listen EADDRINUSE while using nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs)

Answer (score 11):

Your `site.js` tries to listen twice on that port or something (another process) is already listening on port 3000. Find the service and stop/kill it. This command should help: `lsof -i | grep 3000`

Answer (score 6):

Try running `killall node`, then `node site.js` again. If that doesn't work, at least you can rule out Node from the cause of this.

Comment: Try this command: `netstat -tulpn`  

This will list your ports in use, and the programs using them. Here are some [docs](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/11/html/Security_Guide/sect-Security_Guide-Server_Security-Verifying_Which_Ports_Are_Listening.html)

Comment: The `ss` utility should be available -- https://arkit.co.in/ss-utility-investigate-sockets-rhel-7/

Comment: i found other commad for netstat in fedora ( ss -tulpn) and i get this
http://i.imgur.com/1Iv0nhl.png

Comment: `ss` should list all of your ports currently in use. Port 3000 will be in there somewhere if it's being used by another program.

Comment: If i change port 3000 to other np 4512 i get still same error but without ports 3000... :v

Comment: works for me. But i did not understand why some process rest appended. i put it in package.json: "kill": "killall node"

Answer (score -2):

Your site is listening twice to that port. You can check in your code whether you have 2 instructions .listen()