# nodejs crashing at end of script

Tags: node.js

I am having a very strange crash in nodejs, the error is

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1020:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1258:14)
at listen (net.js:1294:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1390:5)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\tyler\Desktop\workspace\stream pop-up\index.js:18:6)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
```

and my code is

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var fs = require("fs");
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/popup.html');
});

fs.watchFile("assets/popup.json", {interval:100}, function(curr, prev)
{
    console.log("working")//dosen't go here
    fs.readFile("assets/popup.json",{encoding:"utf8"}, function(err, data){
        io.emit("popup", data)
    })
});
http.listen(port, function()
{
  console.log("working")//doesn't go here
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
console.log("working") //this one prints
```

the exact same code was working a before, the only difference was I put this file, along with the node_modues in a subfolder, and then took them out of that subfolder, because I was getting the same error. I have no idea why this is happening, and any help would be appreciated

edit: I now know that the problem is the port is in use, but I don't know why. I tried using a python script subprocess.Popen t call this script, but it errored out after the next line of code was ran (the creation of a tkinter window)

Comment: `listen EADDRINUSE :::3000` typically means you have another process using the same port? Are you sure you don't have an instance of your script running somewhere else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Error: listen EADDRINUSE while using nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your port 3000 already in use. Try to change port 3000 or kill the script running in this port.
If you are using Linux or Unix, try to run this command to verify port is in use:

```
 sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN
```

Or in Windows:

```
netstat -a -b
```

Comment: i tried to use python to run the script, but i also needed to do other things with the python so the script crashed, but left the port in use somewhere i guess, is there any way to fix that?

Comment: sorry, using windows

Comment: okay, that would probably have worked but i was able to stop the script running in eclipse(what i use for python) by useing the terminate all scripts button. i must have started the scrit running, but never properly ended it because that worked

Answer (score 1):

The port 3000 is already in use, you could try to change port 3000 to some other port or kill the instance running in the port 3000.

on mac and linux

```
 killall node
```

on windows

```
 taskkill /f /im node.exe
```