# Encountered a problemin my first node.js code andi can't understand what went wrong

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am new in node.js and encountered a problem in my first code:===>

```
var http = require('http');      
http.createServer(function (req, res) {         
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});         
res.end('Hello World!');     
}).listen(8080);
```

it throws this error:=====>>

```
events.js:182       
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event       
^  Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080     
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1041:11)     
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1064:20)     
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1322:14)     
at listenInCluster (net.js:1370:12)     
at Server.listen (net.js:1466:7)     
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Tuladhar\nodeJS.js:6:4)     
at Module._compile (module.js:573:30)     
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:584:10)     
at Module.load (module.js:507:32)     
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
```

Can anyone please help me

Comment: do you already have a server running? Maybe in another tab? The other thing too is that the process might still be running. I would check the processes in your Activity Monitor

Comment: no i did check before running the program

Comment: Your port is already in use by another process. Try another port. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Error: listen EADDRINUSE while using nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs)

Answer (score 3):

The error `Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080` means that some other process is already using port 8080.  Switch your port and try again.

Comment: I tried switching port. It doesn't show anthing, it neither runs nor shows any errors. just blank screen.

Answer (score 0):

well if anyone ever encounters this problem, open your node command prompt and install http-server like this:
npm install http-server -g

atleast mine worked by applying this method.

Comment: you don't offer any insight as to why this would work. I can't see why this would.

Comment: it installs the missing library that supports the methods used in this code