# How do i fix this: Error: listen EADDRINUSE ... ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp

How do i fix the issue below?

**system:** 
gulp
npm 
windows

**issue:** 
... Uhoh. Got error listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:35729 ...
    Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:35729
        at Object._errnoException (util.js:1021:11)
        at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
        at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1344:14)
        at listenInCluster (net.js:1385:12)
        at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1494:7)
        at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:100:10)
    events.js:182
          throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8000
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1021:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1043:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1344:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1385:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1494:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:100:10)
```

Comment: is a port used ;), try to change the port

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Error: listen EADDRINUSE while using nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

Means that you have already used `127.0.0.1:8000` host with another application. Change the host of your current application or stop the mentioned one.

Comment: well. I found out that the .git recovery is helpin the issue. Strange. What if i want to start with a clean .git log and meantain a working app?

Comment: @fleurloves Glad to help you

Answer (score 0):

`EADDRINUSE` means that the port number which `listen()` tries to bind the server to is already in use.
Try another port or close the program using that port.