# How to create style for a React JS component class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to write inline css for a React JS component called Login, but it shows an error. Why? What's the correct way to do an in-line component css?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Button} from 'semantic-ui-react'
import '../css/login.css'

class Login extends Component {

    constructor(){
        super();
        this.login_style = {
            marginTop: '10%',
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ui eight wide column centered grid login_box" style={this.login_style}>
                <div className="four wide column login_login">
                    <h2 className="ui image header centered">
                        <div className="content">
                            Log-in to your account
                        </div>
                    </h2>
```

The error message

```
events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8000
    at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1367:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1492:7)
    at Function.listen (/Users/Wanhui/Desktop/TeamSolid/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Wanhui/Desktop/TeamSolid/bin/www:3:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
    at loader (/Users/Wanhui/Desktop/TeamSolid/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/Wanhui/Desktop/TeamSolid/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
```

Comment: What's the error ?

Comment: @LoremIpsum The error message doesn't make sense to me

Comment: Does the error happen when you don't use inline style ?

Comment: @LoremIpsum No. If I delete style attribute and the object, I don't have an error

Comment: how do you build your project ?

Comment: @LoremIpsum create-react-project, run with npm start

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Error: listen EADDRINUSE while using nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is not related to styles but it is because some other process is running on port 8000. Kill the process running on port 8000. Check [this](http://this) answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use the Terminal to kill React processes

```
ps | grep react
*this shows all running processes with react in name*
kill 64985 64986
*kills react related processes*
```

If needed, restart on a different port.