# Re-Use same port for server.listen() in nodejs

Tags: node.js, linux, express, port

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 and have Express 4.16.3.
Everytime I run the server, I have to change the listening port.

The error message I get is:

> listen EADDRINUSE :::8080

**server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
const server = express();

server.get('/',(req,res)=>{
  res.send('Helo Express');
});

server.listen(8080, ()=>{
  console.info('Listening on port 8080');
});
```

Could someone explain as to why this could be happening?
And suggest a possible work-around?

Comment: How are you stopping the old server before starting a new one?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your operative system has the port 8080 being used by another process.

Check with: `sudo nmap -sT -O localhost` if you are using the port 8080 and if so, just change for your Node.js server the number of the port to listen for one it is not being used.

Comment: The first time I run server.js, it runs. The second time I run it is when I get this Error. NMAP result shows 8080 has http-proxy service running on it. I feel the process is not terminated and i still running. all ports from 8080-8087, I had the same problem. I think node is not able to close the connection even after the server.js execution was terminated. could it be a Permissions Issue?

Comment: So your problem is that you are trying to run again the server without closing the previous connection deployed. You can do it manually by hitting `CTRL+C` on the terminal window that executes the Node.js process.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a work around to solve your problem.
Can you please try using [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon). As this would automatically restart your server if any changes is detected in your code (i.e. it restarts your server on file changes).

So you would run your server using the below command:

> nodemon server.js

if the above does not work then use this

```
const port = 8080
function startServer() {

  server.listen(port, err => {
    if(err) {
        port++;
        startServer()
    } else {
       console.log('Server running on port:', port)
    }
  })
}
```

This will scan for a free port and then print the same on the console.

Answer (score 0):

I made a shell script and automated the killing process.

**nkill.sh**

```
pid=$(pgrep node);
pida=($pid);
for ((i=0;i<${#pida[*]};i++));
do 
sudo kill -9 ${pida[$i]};
echo "Killing "${pida[$i]};
done
echo "!!KILLS COMPLETE!!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `server.close()` to release the port.  But, this should be run as you exit.

I use [inits](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inits) to manage my startup and shutdown, I'm working on some sample code to illustrate it, but it's pretty straightforward if you read its docs.

---

Edit:  I'm getting a bit out of date, server.close isn't in Express 4.  But, this begs the question, how are you starting and stopping your application now?  It really looks like the last instance is left running when you try to start a new one.

Comment: It's a tutorial that I'm following. I use Babel-node server.js to run. That's it.

Answer (score -1):

As the error implies, your nodeJS app is trying to listen to port 8080 but that port is already in use by another application which may not necessarily be a node app, you can easily resolve this by changing the port to another port e.g 4000 that you know is free.

Additionally, if you insist on using port 8080, check if you have skype or any other app using port 8080 and close them before trying again.

Comment: The first time I run server.js, it runs. The second time I run it is when I get this Error. NMAP result shows 8080 has http-proxy service running on it.

Comment: you can try the solutions suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs.