# Testing with Mocha and Super test: Uncaught error outside test suite

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, supertest

While testing my api endpoints using mocha and supertest I got some of my test passing and some are not. The error message I got was uncaught error outside test suite: Uncaught error: listen EADDRINUSE:::5000

Comment: Probably some tests are executed in parallel and multiple test backends try listening on port 5000. Check other answer for EADDRINUSE error, like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs

Answer (score -2):

Even I have faced same issue. This is because supertest keep on listening port even after completing the execution of test cases. So, run the mocha command with `--exit` flag. Before running `npm test` make sure there is no service running on the specified port

```
...
"scripts": {
     "start": "node server.js",
     "test": "mocha --exit"
 },
...
```