# EADDRINUSE when watching tests with mocha and supertest

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, tdd, bdd, chai

I'm trying to do BDD tests to cover my code, but I got this error :
I'm trying to do BDD tests to cover my code, but I got this error :
I'm trying to do BDD tests to cover my code, but I got this error :
I'm trying to do BDD tests to cover my code, but I got this error :
I'm trying to do BDD tests to cover my code, but I got this error :
app.js

```
"use strict";

var app = require("express")();

var pg = require("pg");
var http = require("http");
var https = require("https");


require("./config/config");
var server;
swaggerTools.initializeMiddleware(swaggerConfig, function (middleware) {
  // Interpret Swagger resources and attach metadata to request - must be first in swagger-tools middleware chain
  app.use(middleware.swaggerMetadata());
  var sayHello = ( type ) => {
    return ( ) => {
      console.log( `${global.gConfig.app.name} (${global.gConfig.app.desc}) listening for ${type.toUpperCase()} connections on port ${global.gConfig.ports[type]}`);
    }
  }
  if( global.gConfig.ports.http ) {
     http.createServer(app).listen( global.gConfig.ports.http, sayHello('http') );
     server=app.listen(global.gConfig.ports.http);
  }
  if( global.gConfig.ports.https ) {
     server=app.listen(global.gConfig.ports.https);
  }
});
module.exports = {
  serve:server,
  app:app
};
```

test.js

```
let chai = require('chai');
let expect = require('chai').expect; 
let chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
var app=require('../').app;
var server=require('../').server;
let should = require('chai').should; 
var request = require("supertest").agent(server);
chai.use(chaiHttp);

describe('Caracteristiques', () => {
    after(function (done) {
        server.close();
        done();
    });
    it('returns an array of Carateristiques', (done) => {
        //chai.request(server)
        request
            .get('caracteristiques')
            .set('Authorization', 'Bearer token')
            .end((err, res) => {
                 console.log("res :",res);
                 expect(res.status).to.equal(200); 
              done();
            });
      });
})
```

the error :

```
1) Uncaught error outside test suite:
 Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3001
  at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
  at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
  at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1355:14)
  at listenInCluster (net.js:1396:12)
  at Server.listen (net.js:1480:7)
  at Function.listen (node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
  at C:\Users\zya\Documents\Tdbc-api\tdbc-api\app.js:75:17
  at C:\Users\zya\Documents\Tdbc-api\tdbc-api\node_modules\swagger-tools\index.js:85:7
  at cbWrapper (node_modules\swagger-tools\lib\specs.js:1023:5)
  at validateSwagger2_0 (node_modules\swagger-tools\lib\specs.js:1018:3)
  at validateSemantically (node_modules\swagger-tools\lib\specs.js:1028:5)
  at C:\Users\zya\Documents\Tdbc-api\tdbc-api\node_modules\swagger-tools\lib\specs.js:1221:7
  at C:\Users\zya\Documents\Tdbc-api\tdbc-api\node_modules\swagger-tools\lib\specs.js:1061:29
  at C:\Users\zya\Documents\Tdbc-api\tdbc-api\node_modules\swagger-tools\lib\specs.js:707:12
  at C:\Users\zya\Documents\Tdbc-api\tdbc-api\node_modules\swagger-tools\lib\specs.js:683:9
  at <anonymous>
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
  at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
  at bootstrap_node.js:612:3

2) Caracteristiques
   returns an array of Carateristiques:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'address' of undefined
  at Test.serverAddress (node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:55:18)
  at new Test (node_modules\supertest\lib\test.js:36:12)
  at TestAgent.(anonymous function) [as get] (node_modules\supertest\lib\agent.js:52:15)
  at Context.it (test\caracteristiques.js:31:14)

3) Caracteristiques
   "after all" hook:
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'close' of undefined
  at Context.<anonymous> (test\caracteristiques.js:23:16)
```

I think the set up id good, can any one helop please ?

Comment: port 3001 can only be used once. You need to update your configs to use different ports.

Comment: there are two ports used,3001 and 3000 for developement enviroment i use 3001

Comment: Well, something is using port 3001.

Comment: this is the problem, because the server and test are using the same port

Comment: Try this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53505588/9438572) to stop mocha.

Answer (score 3):

i think it's not working because you are trying to enable the server in the same port each time your test is executed. [Or you have your sever running while you execute your tests].

Try to shut down your server while you execute your tests.

FYI: You are exporting your server main module as "serve", then you try to acceed to it using require(path).server instead of require(path).serve;