# kill -9 recreates the process with new PID

Tags: node.js, process

I have Node app running on port 9800.
It's now throwing an `Error listen EADDRINUSE :::9800`.

I have looked up stackoverflow and tried all of those answered.
[stackoverflow reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs)

But none of them worked for me.
kill -9 is not killing the process. It just recreates the process with new PID.

Here is the detail.

```
MacBook-Pro-2:portfolio jiahlee$ lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
rapportd  404 jiahlee    3u  IPv4 0x75aeedfca27f06f5      0t0  TCP *:49170 (LISTEN)
rapportd  404 jiahlee    4u  IPv6 0x75aeedfca221604d      0t0  TCP *:49170 (LISTEN)
Python    800 jiahlee    3u  IPv4 0x75aeedfca7815d95      0t0  TCP localhost:24679 (LISTEN)
node     3071 jiahlee   12u  IPv6 0x75aeedfca221438d      0t0  TCP *:9800 (LISTEN)
MacBook-Pro-2:portfolio jiahlee$ kill -9 3071
MacBook-Pro-2:portfolio jiahlee$ lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
rapportd  404 jiahlee    3u  IPv4 0x75aeedfca27f06f5      0t0  TCP *:49170 (LISTEN)
rapportd  404 jiahlee    4u  IPv6 0x75aeedfca221604d      0t0  TCP *:49170 (LISTEN)
Python    800 jiahlee    3u  IPv4 0x75aeedfca7815d95      0t0  TCP localhost:24679 (LISTEN)
node     3119 jiahlee   12u  IPv6 0x75aeedfca2215a8d      0t0  TCP *:9800 (LISTEN)
MacBook-Pro-2:portfolio jiahlee$ sudo kill -9 3119
MacBook-Pro-2:portfolio jiahlee$ lsof -PiTCP -sTCP:LISTEN
COMMAND   PID    USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
rapportd  404 jiahlee    3u  IPv4 0x75aeedfca27f06f5      0t0  TCP *:49170 (LISTEN)
rapportd  404 jiahlee    4u  IPv6 0x75aeedfca221604d      0t0  TCP *:49170 (LISTEN)
Python    800 jiahlee    3u  IPv4 0x75aeedfca7815d95      0t0  TCP localhost:24679 (LISTEN)
node     3154 jiahlee   12u  IPv6 0x75aeedfca221438d      0t0  TCP *:9800 (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like node process is initiated by some parent process so even when you kill the node process it starts again

Can you give me the output of below command

```
lsof -n | grep 1337 | grep LISTEN
```

Comment: what is the python process for can you kill that too

Comment: I tried to kill python process. but it's also recreated with new PID.

Comment: I am not sure why this python process is working. I am not running any python app. never used this language.

Comment: I turned off my computer and restarted it. And somehow it works now.

Comment: ha ha at last the final