# How to fix "Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000" Unhandled 'error' event

Tags: node.js

i create a nodejs server (a loginapp) but when i try to node app a error (she was not here before) came out :

```
events.js:167
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1290:14)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1338:12)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1425:7)
    at Function.listen (C:\Users\Corentin\Documents\loginapp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:618:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Corentin\Documents\loginapp\app.js:81:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:742:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at emitErrorNT (net.js:1317:8)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)
```

I think there is a link with mongo but i didnt see the error,

This is my app.js code (NOT FULL) ask me if you need more of my code

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var session = require('express-session');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local'),Strategy;
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/loginapp', { useNewUrlParser: true });
var db = mongoose.connection;

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

// APP INIT
var app = express();

// VIEW ENGINE
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'));
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaultLayout:'layout' }));
app.set('view engine','handlebars');

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// SET PORT
app.set('port', (5000));

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Server lancé sur le port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

This is my users.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var User = require('../models/user');

// REGISTER
router.get('/register', (req, res) => {
    res.render('register');
});

// LOGIN
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
    res.render('login');
});

// REGISTER
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    var name = req.body.name;
    var username = req.body.username;
    var email = req.body.email;
    var password = req.body.password;
    var password2 = req.body.password2;

    // VALIDATION
    req.checkBody('name','Name is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('username','Username is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('email','Email is not valid').isEmail();
    req.checkBody('password','Password is required').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('password2','Passwords do not match').equals(req.body.password);

    var errors = req.validationErrors();

    if(errors) {
        res.render('register', {
            errors:errors
        });
    } else {
        var newUser = new User({
            name: name,
            username: username,
            email: email,
            password: password
        });

        User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user) {
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(user);
        });

        req.flash('success_msg', 'You are now registered and u can log');

        res.redirect('/users/login');
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

And the user.js file

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

// USER SCHEMA
var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
        index: true
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    password: {
        type: String
    }
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
        });
    });
}
```

Thank a lot to the person who can help me !

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs/50169168

Comment: its not working for me

Comment: try to restart your machine. if it does not help. try to use another port

Comment: Possibly duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632667/how-to-kill-the-process-currently-using-a-port-on-localhost-in-windows

Comment: The same happened to me started a simple app only listen to port for now. Changed the port and restarted but nothing helped. Also tried to see what the process was and kill it. How it is possible for node to occupy the port even before started and moreover every single time? What is going on?

Answer (score 56):

Try this one

```
sudo lsof -i :5000
```

COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE  SIZE/OFF  NODE  NAME
node      20152 abc    21u  IPv6  195004       0t0   TCP  *:http (LISTEN)

```
sudo kill -9 20152
```

Answer (score 40):

This works for me:

```sh
sudo killall -9 node
```

Comment: This worked with me as well. Just killing the port using PID didn't work for me.

Comment: Anyone able to fix this in Azure node app service? it's been a pain.

Answer (score 8):

If you are on a **mac** port 5000 will by default be used by **AirPlay**.

To turn AirPlay off and thereby free up port 5000:

1. System Preferences
2. Sharing
3. Untick AirPlay in the left column

This has fixed the problem for me.

MacBook Air 2020 
Apple M1 
macOS Monterey 12.6 
16/256GB

Comment: This was bugging me for a while, but this fixed it. Thanks

Comment: It worked for me as well.Thanks alot

Answer (score 6):

I had this error and what I did wrong was I declared the `app.listen()` twice and hence the port was already in use. Make sure you only do it once.

Answer (score 5):

**on windows:**

1. Run the cmd as administrator (hold `ctl + shift` while clicking on it - or right-click and choose `Run as Administrator`)
2. Run the command below to find the PID of the process:

```
netstat -ano|findstr "PID :8081"  // replace 8081 with your in-use port
```

You'll get a result like:

[image]

3. Run the following command using the target PID number:

```
// replace 1500 with your target PID

taskkill /pid 1500 /f
```

Answer (score 4):

Your express server tries to open Port 500

```
app.set('port', (5000));
```

And the error message suggests, that this port is already in use.

You can either change the port of the express server or find the application that uses port 5000 and see if you can change the port there.

Does this help?

Comment: i restard my vs code and my terminal and its work ! thk for helping

Answer (score 3):

I found that **`fuser -k 5000/tcp`** is the most quick way to kill a process on a specific port.

Answer (score 2):

Try `sudo pkill node`. Don't forget to use `sudo` permission. It's really worked for me.

I tried `kill -9 PID`. but it reoccurs on every `rs`.

Answer (score 1):

You should try :

```
netstat -lpn | grep 5000
```

and then :

```
kill -9 PID
```

Comment: "netstat: n: unknown or uninstrumented protocol"

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but maybe someone will find this useful.

In order to be more efficient, I added the following bash script to an alias in bashrc file, so I don't have to type `lsof -i:5000`, then copy the PID, then run `kill -9 PID`.

In the *.bashrc* (you can find it normally in the path *~/.bashrc*), put somewhere inside it the following:

```
alias k5k='lsof -t -i:5000 | xargs kill -9'
```

I named this alias **k5k** for "kill 5 thousand(k)", but you name it whatever you want.

Then you can just type `k5k` and it will kill all instances running on port 5000.

Answer (score 1):

I just close all the windows of IDE or command prompt and restart the machine. It worked fine for me. Hopefully, there's some random program running on that specific port.

Answer (score 1):

sudo lsof -t -i tcp:portNumber | xargs kill -9

This will work if your portNumber is already in use with another app.js file.

Comment: Probably don't recommend `kill -9`; it should only be used in desperate situations when a regular `kill` does not work.

Answer (score 0):

you have two terminals open  with open connection to port 5000 , kill one !

Comment: Or better yet kill all and restart `pkill -9 node` then start up client and or server.

Answer (score 0):

restart your laptop/server, it will release all the busy ports, then try again...u can also use

```
ps aux | grep node
```

and then  kill the process using:

```
kill -9 PID
```

but most of the times it wont work for nodemon, and didnt work for me.

Answer (score 0):

this error is showing because your mongodb is running... i.e mongod. so first exit from that and then restart your visual studio code.. it will definetly work.

Answer (score 0):

Specific port running checker

> sudo netstat -lpn |grep :5000

tcp6     |  0    |  0 :::5000       |          :::*            |        LISTEN   |   6782/java

> kill 6782

--------------------- OR ---------------------

> sudo lsof -t -i:5000

> sudo kill -9 $(sudo lsof -t -i:5000)

Answer (score 0):

I just restart the terminal and run again:

> npm start

it will work fine again

(I'm using ubuntu terminal)

Answer (score 0):

This is the *Error* that happens when we are using the *same port number* in another websites or you are trying to run the application in the terminal at the *same time* that application was running on another *terminal*.
For me, The Situation was that I was already running the node Application in my terminal But I am trying to run it again using npm start command on the other terminal so that it shows this error.
**Solution:** You can check whether your application is running or not in the terminal or command prompt. If it was running then you can quit it and run it again then it will be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have another app running on that port in another window, Happened to me.
You can also change the port to maybe 5500 or another number and run it. It should work

Answer (score 0):

Just kill all the ports, reload the page and use the command:

```bash
npm start
```

This worked quite for me
Thanks !!

Answer (score -1):

`netstat -ano | findstr :5000`
and after this simply, type
`taskkill /F /PID yourNumber(11076)`

then start, server use:
`npm run dev`

Comment: This seems to duplicate the answer by Mahdieh Shavandi, with much less detail and explanation.