# Mongoose ,Unable to connect

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-web-server

Mongodb is connected put in req and red json is giving empty braces it is not showing the body.

This is my Input:

```
{
  "name": "mansi",
  "email": "exaplle@gmail.com",
  "password": "hiihh"
}
```

This is my output (error):

```
**PS D:\React\inotebook\backend> nodemon index.js
[nodemon] 2.0.16
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): .
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
node:events:505
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1372:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1420:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1508:7)
    at Function.listen (D:\React\inotebook\backend\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635:24)       
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\React\inotebook\backend\index.js:15:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1399:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -4091,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3000
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...**
```

Comment: What does 'red json' mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000" Unhandled 'error' event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54468097/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-5000-unhandled)

Answer (score 0):

```
EADDRINUSE: address already in use
```

Port 3000 is already in use by another app. Since you're using Powershell, run:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection | where Localport -eq 3000 | select Localport,OwningProcess
```

on Powershell to find out what the app is.