# Error: listen EADDRINUSE node.js even though nothing is running

Tags: node.js, npm, webfaction

I installed a new application on my webfaction server and when I try to run it using `node app` or `npm start` I get this error:

`Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::15120`

Even though this particular port is free and nothing is running there. I have another node.js app running using `pm2` on a different port.

How can I avoid this error coming up?

Doesn't happen on my local server.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix Error: listen EADDRINUSE while using nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs)

Comment: Are you sure that this port is free? Try to inspect it with netstat -plnt and check if it really is.

Comment: the port is not free at all, can you check it using this command and see the associated pid? sudo lsof -i :15120