# How to connect Node Js server with Android Studio app?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, express, android-volley

I'm trying to establish connection between an *android studio* and a *node js* server, but I'm kinda stuck. I pretty sure I've done many things wrong, but my one error message I can start searching for solution from is a *listen EADDRINUSE :::3000* error on the Node server side. Here are all the codes from both sides, I really hope some more experienced eyes can point out the issue and give me a direction to continue at. Thanks in advance!

**Node JS code:**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.on('listening',function(){
    console.log('ok, server is running');
});

app.post('/postdata', (req, res) => {
    var data = req.body.data; // your data
    // do something with that data (write to a DB, for instance)
    console.log(data)
    res.status(200).json({
        message: "Data received successfully"
    });
});
app.listen(3000);
```

**Android Studio code**(MainActivity.java)**:**

```
package com.example.tbg_studio;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button RequestButton; // button which on clicking, sends the request
    TextView DisplayText; // a text field to display the request response
    EditText DataField; // a text field where the data to be sent is entered

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RequestButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.RequestButton);
        DataField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.DataField);
        DisplayText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.DisplayText);

        final RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        final String url = "http://serverdomainorip/postdata"; // your URL

        queue.start();
        RequestButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
                params.put("data", DataField.getText().toString()); // the entered data as the body.

                JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new
                        JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                        url,
                        new JSONObject(params),
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                try {
                                    DisplayText.setText(response.getString("message"));
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        DisplayText.setText("That didn't work!");
                    }
                });
                queue.add(jsObjRequest);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

and the **Node JS error message:**

> Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
>       at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
>       at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
>       at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1367:14)
>       at listenInCluster (net.js:1408:12)
>       at Server.listen (net.js:1492:7)
>       at Function.listen (/home/leventecsoba/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
>       at Object. (/home/leventecsoba/Asztal/Node JS/tbg_studio.js:16:5)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:565:32)

Comment: AS the error says.You have already one server running on port 3000

Comment: Alright, how do I solve it? :)

Comment: Check this  SO post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs

Comment: I killed the running process, got rid of the error message. But the server isn't running(theres no ok, its running log message).

Comment: `kill $(lsof -i:3000 -t)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you already have something (probably another instance of a Node server) running at `:3000`, so the code itself does not really matter. If killing processes does not make it for you, simply restart your computer (I know, it sounds silly, but it usually works!). With a fresh start, you'll be able to take control of port `3000` again and run the Node server you want there.

Alternatively, you change this line in your Node server to have it listen for requests on port `3001`:

```
app.listen(3001)
```

You'll have to also update the code in Android Studio to have your mobile app send requests to port `3001`.

Comment: OK, sound good :)
Quick question, the update needed in the android studio code should be in the `final String url = "http://serverdomainorip/postdata";` line, right? So like I sould change it to http://3001/postdata? Just to be sure :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know enough about Android Studio and Java to answer your question with confidence but from what I understand your URL would look something like this: `http://serverdomainorip:3001/postdata` or try that if you want to make sure it hits `localhost`: `http://192.168.1.1:3001/postdata`. If this works for you, don't forget to select this answer as valid for your question :)

Comment: Didn't work, but thanks for the effort, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

On your url pass the port where you want to connect.

```
  final String url = "http://serverdomainorip:3000/postdata";
```