# How to fix EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000?

Tags: node.js, express

[terminal after trying to run server server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw8IX.png)

```js
const express = require('express')

const colors = require('colors')

const dotenv = require('dotenv').config()


const {errorHandler} = require('./middleware/errorMiddleware')


const connectDB = require('./config/db')

const port =  process.env.PORT || 5000


connectDB()

const app = express()

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}))


app.use('/api/goals', require('./routes/goalRoutes') )


app.use(errorHandler)


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port} `) )
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Error: listen EADDRINUSE while using NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs)

Comment: Please don't just dump your code along with an *image* of your error. Please adhere to our various guidelines and quality standards on [ask].

Comment: Sorry i've posted in a wrong way because i'm still new to stackoverflow ..

Answer (score -1):

There is already an application listening on port 5000, like the error message suggests. Close any other command prompt/bash that may be running an instance of the application and try again.

Comment: Thank a lot, the first problem is solved but the app still crushing... :( i don't know what i did wrong

Answer (score -1):

Port 5000 is already in use by another application. Either close this port or choose an unused port by:

Changing: `const port =  process.env.PORT || 5000` to `const port =  process.env.PORT || <otherport>`

or by providing an unused port as an environmental variable.