# Running the node server with port value from .env file creates a error on restart of server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, environment-variables

i have a simple node application in which i have added the port number in the .env file but while using `app.listen(process.env.PORT,()=>{})` the server runs fir the first time and on running again it throws an error stating that the same port number is a running .
The error thrown is

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 4001,
```

And here are my server file setup

```
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
dotenv.config();

const port = process.env.PORT,
 
// Server Startup

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log("Server started ");
});
```

Here is the .env file

```
# Server configuration 
PORT=4001,
```

And in additional of the error created a new unknown file gets created in the name of the port number(i.e 4001)  in the root folder also.

Why this weird behavior anybody sort it out

Comment: `Error: listen EADDRINUSE` means you already have an app listening on that port. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs) question and answers.

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate the behavior you have mentioned, however, you should remove the following commas after `process.env.PORT` and in the .env file after `PORT=4001`.

The condition you have described seems like the port is still in use by a hanging process.  Check your processes using "top" or "ps aux" and kill the hanging process using 'kill' (man kill)