# Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000 Tried every method

Tags: node.js, express

Not able to kill the already in use port issue.

I have been  trying to kill the process with PID but it keeps popping up and when i try to change the port in the main javascript file, command won't go along. it would get stuck and had to kill it.

Posting my code and terminal screenshots.

1. [Terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KLcId.png)
2. [Terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPGc4.jpg)

Here is my code

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/user', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('<h1>User: ' + req.body.username + '</h1>');
});

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send(
    '<form action="/user" method="POST"><input type="text" name="username"><button type="submit">Create User</button></form>'
  );
  
});

  app.listen(5000);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix Error: listen EADDRINUSE while using NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs)

Comment: Hi, using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you

Answer (score -1):

This for linux and mac os(Unix-like systems)

Run

```bash
$ sudo lsof -i :5000
```

Then kill the process using the process id you see in the output of the above command.

```bash
sudo kill <pid here> # ex: sudo kill 19253
```

If that's not helpful use the task manager on your system. Otherwise simply reboot