# Listen EADDRINUSE phonegap windows

Tags: node.js, cordova, phonegap-desktop-app

Hi there I'm pretty new on Phonegap, I've installed the desktop version on windows but when I launch my app I've this error **listen EADDRINUSE**

If you think that i can find the answer here [how to release localhost from Error: listen EADDRINUSE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553957/how-to-release-localhost-from-error-listen-eaddrinuse) Please explain me more because I don't understand the answer

**I've changed the port but every time I have the same error. I'm sure that it's something stupid or small, can someone help me please?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to release localhost from Error: listen EADDRINUSE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553957/how-to-release-localhost-from-error-listen-eaddrinuse)

Comment: please explain me more because I can't understand the answer of this topic

Comment: Were you able to successfully run the application once? Does this problem rectify after a reboot?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It seems some versions have been experiencing this problem. Take a look at this [link](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/issues/518), it discusses which versions suffer from this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
killall -9 node
```

Please try this