# Zombie.js Mink Behat not working

Tags: php, bdd, behat, mink, zombie.js

I have been struggling with getting to zombie.js work with mink behat. Below is the minimized version of my files.

**composer.json**

```
{
  "require": {
    "behat/mink": "^1.7",
    "behat/mink-zombie-driver": "^1.4"
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "zombie": "^4.2.1"
  }
}
```

**index.php**

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\ZombieDriver(
    new \Behat\Mink\Driver\NodeJS\Server\ZombieServer()
);

$session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);

$session->start();
```

This is what I get when I run this.

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught RuntimeException: Server process has been terminated: (1) [events.js:160
>           throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
>           ^
>
>     Error: listen EADDRINUSE 127.0.0.1:8124
>         at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
>         at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1049:20)
>         at Server._listen2 (net.js:1253:14)
>         at listen (net.js:1289:10)
>         at net.js:1399:9
>         at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:11)
>         at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
>         at Module.runMain (module.js:592:11)
>         at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
>         at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
>         at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
>     ] in /Users/me/Web/mink/vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/NodeJS/Server.php:413
>     Stack trace:
>     #0 /Users/me/Web/mink/vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/NodeJS/Server.php(306): Behat\Mink\Driver\NodeJS\Server->checkAvailability()
>     #1 /Users/me/Web/mink/vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/ZombieDriver.php(64): Behat\Mink\Driver\NodeJS\Serv in **/Users/me/Web/mink/vendor/behat/mink-zombie-driver/src/NodeJS/Server.php** on line **413**

this is whats on my machine

```
$ php --version
PHP 7.0.10 (cli) (built: Aug 21 2016 19:14:33) ( NTS )
$ node --version
v6.5.0
$ npm --version
3.10.7
```

Answer (score 0):

After searching some more I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17767468/2644202), and it turned out just a problem of address already in use.