# Node + MongoDB issue EADDRINUSE

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Trying to build an experimental CRUD app, however there is an issue connecting to db.

Using mLab free db. 
No matter which port is specified the error is EADDRINUSE :::

How do I close all Node instances that might be using these ports?

Comment: use ps aux | grep node to find all the node process, and use sudo kill -9 PID to kill the process

Comment: Solution is here->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553957/how-to-release-localhost-from-error-listen-eaddrinuse/22875192#22875192

Answer (score 0):

Solution is already given here.

[How to fix Error: listen EADDRINUSE while using nodejs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898372/how-to-fix-error-listen-eaddrinuse-while-using-nodejs/41248876#41248876)

To check which ports are in use , try this command

```
netstat -ntlp
```

to check node JS processes (instance of your app or other using the same port yu are requesting ) running

```
ps aux | grep -i node
```

and kill relevant processes by

```
kill *process-id* | killall node
```