# getting an error- listen EADDRINUSE :::3000 on windows machine

Tags: node.js, windows, express, terminal, port

I've searched a lot and I understand there is some process or server running on port 3000, but how can I stop that and run a new express http server on port 3000. There are few answers which tell it for Unix environment..but how to release the port on windows environment using cmd terminal.
Closing the task using PID also didn't work for me. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: end the 'node' task from task manager

Answer (score 30):

Open the command prompt and type the following

```
netstat -a -o -n
```

run down the list by port until you find port 3000 and you will see the process id. Then run

```
taskkill /F /PID (yourprocessID)
```

there's another simple way to do this in a single command

```
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :3000') DO TaskKill.exe /PID %%P
```

if you use windows 7 U might need `tokens=5`, use with caution tokens are different for different OS.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for the guide @Gnanesh

Comment: I was able to 'netstat -a -o -n' to determine the PID but the taskkill errored out because of '/F' flag.

Comment: I found this http://tweaks.com/windows/39559/kill-processes-from-command-prompt/ article that was very helpful.

Comment: @user752746 - try this on command prompt: taskkill /pid PIDNO /f   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8553957/how-to-release-localhost-from-error-listen-eaddrinuse

Answer (score 17):

- In windows 10, open task manager and go to `Details` tab.
- There you will find `node.exe` running.
- End that task and your port will be released.

Comment: I was able to remove the node task with this method. thanks!

Comment: Best answer I could have been found

Comment: This is what ultimately did it for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using VS Code in Windows, You would need to first **KILL** all the previous instances of your Node-App

Afterwards, Open the BASH terminal in VS Code and run below command

`cmd "/C TASKKILL /IM node.exe /F"`

Answer (score 0):

EADDRINUSE means there is already another running process that is listening to the port your node app wants to use and has it reserved. It's most likely you've run the app previously but it hasn't terminated properly and is still holding on to the port.
so first we terminate already running one,then only start another new one server

Answer (score 0):

That's because port 3000 is already busy listening to another process.
so just go to task manager and end that process/ delete all node js related processes.